# Apache Commons HTTP vs built-In packages for Java

Tags: java, http, client, apache-httpcomponents

I know how popular Apache Commons java package is for HTTP related purposes. What advantages are there to using it over the packages that are built into the JDK. Namely:

com.sun.net.httpserver and java.net

I like the API for these better and feel like I can do whatever I need to do with them. Does Apache just have the network effect going or are there true advantages?

Comment: the main advantage is that with Apache HTTP you operate requests, responses and clients as with usual objects, without need to convert/encode/parse them by your own; you also don't need manage connections, control their state and so on.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache HTTP packages are easy to use and developer friendly as compared to built-in JDK packages. 
Apache packages are usually designed to solve the common development problems. In other words, we may end up writing lesser code if use Apache packages (and that's the reason they are popular).

Comment: Thank you. Your feedback is appreciated.